# using foreach to save data not save courses correctly(delete previous courses

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6

**Needs**

save name in employee table and save all courses

in employee courses table when click submit button in edit [HTTPPOST]

**Problem summary**

submit button save changes only and delete data exist before

**Problem details**

when click submit button in edit post .courses will save

what i added or selected courses before click submit it will save

but courses that employee have before will delete

**Example**

1- i add employee name MEDO have course c++

2-in edit view it show c++

3-if i add python in edit view then click submit it must have two courses

c++ and python

4- it show to me python only when open edit for this employee again

it save courses selected but courses exist before deleted

**Image for problem**

image found below show all details

[SAVE all courses in employeecourse table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUIlj.jpg)

**Code**

```
public class EditEmployeeVm
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Courses { get; set; }
    public int[] CourseIds { set; get; }
    public List<CourseVm> ExistingCourses { set; get; }
}

public class CourseVm
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
}
in edit function get i pass data to edit view

    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
     var vm = new EditEmployeeVm { Id = id };
            var emp = db.Employees.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Id == id);
            vm.Name = emp.Name;
            vm.ExistingCourses = db.EmployeeCourses
                                    .Where(g => g.EmployeeId == id)
                                    .Select(f => new CourseVm
                                    {
                                        Id = f.Id,
                                        Name = f.Course.CourseName
                                    }).ToList();

            vm.CourseIds = vm.ExistingCourses.Select(g => g.Id).ToArray();
            vm.Courses = db.Courses.Select(f => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = f.Id.ToString(),
                Text = f.CourseName
            }).ToList();

            return View(vm);
    }



[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(EditEmployeeVm model)
        {
            var emp = db.Employees.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Id == model.Id);
            foreach (EmployeeCourse eec in emp.EmployeeCourses.ToList())
            {
                var ec = db.EmployeeCourses.Find(eec.Id);
                db.EmployeeCourses.Remove(ec);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            foreach (var couseid in model.CourseIds)
            {
                db.EmployeeCourses.Add(new EmployeeCourse { CourseId = couseid, EmployeeId = emp.Id });
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            return View();
        }
```

**update**

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(EditEmployeeVm model)
        {
    **//i need to save name employee changes in employee table and all courses in emloyeecourse table
    //what is wrong here**
       var emp = db.Employees
                   .Include(e => e.EmployeeCourses)
                   .FirstOrDefault(f => f.Id == model.Id);

            foreach (var eec in emp.EmployeeCourses.ToList())
            {
                db.EmployeeCourses.Remove(eec);
            }

            foreach (var couseid in model.CourseIds)
            {
                db.EmployeeCourses.Add(new EmployeeCourse { CourseId = couseid, EmployeeId = emp.Id });
            }

            db.SaveChanges();

            return View();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try as shown below.

**Note :** You have to use `Include`to fetch the `EmployeeCourses` as shown below.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(EditEmployeeVm model)
    {

       var emp = db.Employees
                   .Include(e => e.EmployeeCourses)
                   .FirstOrDefault(f => f.Id == model.Id);

            foreach (var eec in emp.EmployeeCourses.ToList())
            {
                db.EmployeeCourses.Remove(eec);
            }

          db.SaveChanges();

            foreach (var couseid in model.CourseIds)
            {
                db.EmployeeCourses.Add(new EmployeeCourse { CourseId = couseid, EmployeeId = emp.Id });
            }

            db.SaveChanges();

            return View();
    }
```

Comment: when i write e => e.EmployeeCourses it give me error cannot convert lambda expression to type string because it is not delegate type

Comment: i do what i write i make  using System.Data.Entity; and i write full code but also not working the result of your code when select new item for course then click submit not save it

Comment: can you put your latest code under `Update` section of your original post ? Then I'll tell what to do.

Comment: Just create a title as `Update` on your post above and then put your latest code after changing according to my suggestion.

Comment: can you show the `Employees` and `EmployeeCourses` models also ?

Comment: employee model and employeecourse table found in this link  http://www.mediafire.com/view/1l18axuzq7wwjs9/employeecourse_model.jpg

Comment: hey,you have to add this `using System.Linq`

Comment: so that what i will do now

Comment: have you added above `namespace` ?

Comment: yes i added two name space  using System.Linq;
using System.Data.Entity;

Comment: same problem before remove old courses and save only new courses meaning must select from drop down courses every time to save

Comment: I have done code change above.Please try that too.added extra  `db.SaveChanges();`.

Comment: i added this db.Savechanges() for every each loop but also nothing changed it remove old data for courses

Comment: no need to do that way.But did you try my change above ? What is the issue now ?

Comment: problem still exist

Comment: suppose i have employee name michel and have one course c++ when this employee  need to take new course for employee michel i will add new course python in edit view the problem when click submit button it will add python(new) and delete c++(old) but actually i have 2 courses c++ and python but when i open edit for employee michel again it will show to me he have one course python that recently added and old deleted what i need actually save new changed and not deleted old